# How to pass locator as parameter in cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, cypress-custom-commands

I wonder if it is possible to pass locators as a parameter to make my function reusable.
I tried to do it myself but I am getting "undefined" instead of working test.
Cypress error:
cy.click() failed because it requires a DOM element.
The subject received was:

> undefined

My code:

```
 Cypress.Commands.add(
  "commandName",
  (locator, chartValue1) => {
    const chartValues = [150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 750, 900];
    for (const value of chartValues) {
      locator.click(value, chartValue1).then(() => {
        mainElementsPage
          .mainSideBarHeader()
          .should("not.include.text", "(pon.)")
          .should("not.include.text", "(wt.)")
          .should("not.include.text", "(śr.)");
      });
    }
  }
);
```

I am using this command in test:

```
    it("should do something", () => {
    cy.commandName(mainElementsPage.chartRect(), 200);
  });
```

mainElementsPage content:

```
class mainElementsPage {

  chartRect() {
    return cy.get("#chart-grid-rect");
  }
}

export default mainElementsPage;
```

Comment: Which one is the locator in your `cypress.commands` ?

Comment: locator in line3 and locator in line6 - this is the parameter. As the attribute, I want to use the correct one in `cy.commandName(mainElementsPage.chartRect(), 200);`

Comment: Assuming `mainElementsPage.chartRect()` returns a locator string, Do you get this locator string in your test where you have written the `cy.commandName()` ? Try logging that.

Comment: It returns Object{5} o0

Comment: Documentations says that Cypress.Command.add accepts only:
"Boolean, String or Array" - so yea, probably it is not possible to pass locator as an argument.

Comment: Please add to the question the function `mainElementsPage`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went this way:

```
 Cypress.Commands.add(
  "commandName",
  (locator, chartValue1) => {
    const chartValues = [150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 750, 900];
    for (const value of chartValues) {
      locator()
      .click(value, chartValue1).then(() => {
        mainElementsPage
          .mainSideBarHeader()
          .should("not.include.text", "(pon.)")
          .should("not.include.text", "(wt.)")
          .should("not.include.text", "(śr.)");
      });
    }
  }
);
```

And in test it looks:

```
it("should do something", () => {
    cy.commandName(mainElementsPage.chartRect, 200);
  });
```

So the thing was about add () to the locator in Cypress.Commands.add() and use locator as string in the test.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you want to make a [child command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands#Child-Commands).

Whatever precedes your custom command is passed in as `subject` (equivalent to `locator`)

```js
Cypress.Commands.add("commandName", {prevSubject: true}, 
  (subject, chartValue1) => {
    const chartValues = [150, 250, 350, 450, 550, 750, 900];
    for (const value of chartValues) {
      subject.click(value, chartValue1).then(() => {
        mainElementsPage.mainSideBarHeader()
          .should("not.include.text", "(pon.)")
          .should("not.include.text", "(wt.)")
          .should("not.include.text", "(śr.)");
      });
    }
  }
)


cy.get("#chart-grid-rect").commandName(200);

// or

mainElementsPage.chartRect().commandName(200);
```

```js
class MainElementsPage {

  chartRect() {
    return cy.get("#chart-grid-rect");
  }
}

export default new MainElementsPage;   // note - new keyword here
```

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you you can use `mainElementsPage` you have to first import this file into your test like this:

```js
import mainElementsPage from '../<some path>/mainElementsPage.js'
```

Then you have to create a object for this, like

```js
const mainElements = new mainElementsPage();
```

Then you can use it as:

```js
mainElements.chartRect()
```

Answer (score 1):

In Cypress, it's impossible to have 2 active command chains simultaneously.
So you cannot pass a command chain into another command ( including a custom command as you do).
So I see 4 different ways of how you can fix the problem:

1. Use a plain function instead of custom command. So you will be able to pass a chain from your POM object.
2. Return a string locator instead of a chain from your
   POM object
3. Use a child command and chain your logic (see @Fody's answer).
4. Pass a *function reference* pointing to your POM object function and call this function *inside the custom command* (see @wojnarto' answer).